# Query get data from database change to array

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I want to make a chart, I have database province and I want to make this be xAxis on Highcharts.

My Database

[image: My Database]

```
<?= \dosamigos\highcharts\HighCharts::widget([
'clientOptions' => [
    'chart' => [
            'type' => 'spline'
    ],
    'title' => [
         'text' => 'Fruit Consumption'
         ],
    'xAxis' => [
        'categories' => [
        'Jabodetabek', 
        'Banten', 
        'Jawa Tengah', 
        'Jawa Timur', 
        'Medan', 
        'Riau', 
        'Bangka Belitung', 
        'Lampung', 
        'Kalimantan Selatan', 
        'Kalimantan Barat', 
        'Kalimantan Timur', 
        'Kalimantan Tengah', 
        'NTB', 
        'NTT', 
        'Papua']
    ],
    'yAxis' => [
        'title' => [
            'text' => 'Fruit eaten'
        ]
    ],
    'plotOptions' => [
        'line' => [
            'dataLabels' => [
                'enabled'=> true
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'series' => [
        ['data' => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    ],

    'responsive' => [
        'rules' => [[
            'condition' => [
                'maxWidth' => 500
            ],
            'charOptions' => [
                'legend' => [
                    'align' => 'center',
                    'verticalAlign' => 'bottom',
                    'layout' => 'horizontal'
                ],

                'yAxis' => [
                    'labels' => [
                        'align' => 'left',
                        'x' => 0,
                        'y' => 0
                    ],
                    'title' => [
                        'text' => null
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]]
    ]
]
```

]);

How can I make the contents of the province table be an array? I want data count all group by provinces.
Please help me

Comment: if you choose to use PDO, you can use http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetchall.php to convert your resultset to an array

Answer (score 0):

The yii2-friendly method is to use gii to generate models for each of your tables.  Then you can get an array like

```
$provinces = \app\models\Province::find()->select('name')->asArray();
```

You can use a similar technique to get the count; I'd post an example except I'm not sure what the correct sql would be for your case.